# How to handle java.rmi.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, initialization, client, rmi

I'm working with Eclipse and the code below is the code that I use for RMI initialization.

```
public void init(String serviceName) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        String url = "rmi://"+ host + serviceName;
        Naming.rebind(url,this);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an `UnknownHostException`.

Since I'm new to this issue, the question may be simple, but I could not handle it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And whats the message of the exception? What's the name of the service. Because if it's "foo" and your host name is myMachine, you'll end up with rmi://myMachinefoo, which will obviously lead to this exception.

Comment: It seems host string value is not recognizable. You are running on your local machine, so you may try 127.0.0.1 or localhost as hardcoded value first. print out what is the host value you are getting now.

Comment: As @JBNizet pointed out, you are missing the slash between the host and service names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnknownHostException means it can't find that host at the network level.  There's no handling this type of exception because it means something is broken.  I'd print out the URL sent to RMI.  It should look something like this:

```
//localhost/ServiceImTryingToAccess
```

If you didn't put a leading "/" on your service it might be:

```
//localhostServiceImTryingToAccess
```

And that certainly would create an UnknownHostException. You really don't need to use InetAddress.getLocalHost() as you could just simply do:

```
String url = "//localhost" + serviceName;
```

Also notice I dropped the rmi:// scheme portion of the URL.  It's in the docs that's not needed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html